# CSS translate with transition creates jumpy animation in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The following snippet is a stripped down example of what appears to be a bug in Firefox.  If the `translate` x axis is greater than the width of the div the transition effect is very choppy.  Tested in other browsers and looks fine everywhere else.  This is also somehow tied in with the `overflow` setting because if I remove it it's fine again in Firefox.

I'm using Firefox v57. Anyone have an idea what's causing this?

```css
div.wrapper {
  transform: translate(100px, 0px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.block {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div.block:hover {
  background-color: #c9302c;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: to add to the weirdness, coincidentally I tried the snippet on a desktop that has not been in use for some years, so it still had Firefox 47, and couldn't  reproduce the issue. Animation looked smooth as silk, just like in other browsers. Then it updated to current version and it started to show the jumpy behaviour. So looks like a bizarre bug generated along the way.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini - thanks for confirming and adding some details.  I've filed a bug - can you please comment there as well? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1431893

Comment: Happening for me when the body has overflow: hidden; and the transformed element is different.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround which is to avoid applying `translate` and `overflow` properties to the same element as follows:

```css
div.wrapper {
  transform: translate(100px, 0px);
}

div.wrapper-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.block {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.block:hover {
  background-color: #c9302c;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-container">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue came up because I was using [Slidebars](https://www.adchsm.com/slidebars/) and the issue described here can be observed even on their website.  Hopefully this Q&A helps some of you who may be running in to the same issue.